# Insulation for 1920s New England home with stucco siding

Tags: insulation, siding, stucco, basement-insulation

I have an old 1920s home with stucco exterior siding, and I've been having work done to improve insulation. Mostly so far this has involved insulating the attic, which also involved air sealing it.

I am also considering air sealing the rim joists in the basement.

I've read a bunch by now that cautions against spraying in cellulose to insulate the walls in their entirety, as the air gap is important for drying out the stucco. So I have a few questions:

1. Is having open air flow at the rim joist also recommended for ventilating the stucco siding?
2. Have I even introduced a potential problem by having my attic air sealed?
3. Have I been misled as to the importance of this whole stucco ventilation thing?
4. Are there any other exterior wall insulation methods that I should be considering which will insulate exterior walls and not lead to moisture problems?

Comment: Have you gotten rid of, or at least established which bays are occupied by knob and tube wiring, and you know you can't insulate those bays until you've decommissioned that?

Comment: There were traces of knob and tube in the attic that I had confirmed were inactive when attic insulation was done. Everything else used in the house is more modern wiring.